# The quote environment and the typographically correct notation of reference

Tags: citing, punctuation, typography, quoting

This is a typography and latex related question.

I have seen various examples of how the `quote` environment and the belonging reference to the quote are used. What is correct in the following minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{natbib}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}

\begin{document}


\begin{quote}
I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller, 
I am an out-of-controller! \citep[p.~123]{Nightrider1979}
\end{quote}

or

\begin{quote}
I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller,
I am an out-of-controller \citep[p.~123]{Nightrider1979}!
\end{quote}

or

\begin{quote}
I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller,
I am an out-of-controller! \citet[p.~123]{Nightrider1979}
\end{quote}

or

\begin{quote}
I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller,
I am an out-of-controller! 
\end{quote} \citep[p.~123]{Nightrider1979}

or

\begin{quote}
I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller,
I am an out-of-controller! 
\end{quote} \citet[p.~123]{Nightrider1979}


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{./quote}


\end{document}
```

Please use the following bibtex file saved as quote.bib in the same directory:

```
@ARTICLE{Nightrider1979,
  author = {Crawford "Nightrider" Montizano},
  title = {Member of Toecutter's gang},
  journal = {Mad Max},
  year = {1979}
}
```

I think whether an author wants to indent the whole `quote` environment, change the font size or put the quote in quotation marks is up to the individual style. I just wondered about the punctuation and the position and style of the reference.

Comment: @jon: Thanks for your comment. You are absolutely right: usually the author is already introduced in the context _before_ the quote. I was more after the `\citet{}` `\citep{}` distinction, the correct punctuation (before or after the `\citep{}` command) and whether the `\citep{}` command is within the `quote` environment or outside.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I'd say it is (semantically, if parenthetically) part of the quotation, so I'd keep it inside the environment.  Consider, e.g., a footnote citation style: the footnotemark belongs in the quotation environment, but the footnote content belongs at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

As @Roman asked in his coment I would say all his given examples are suboptimal.

I would use this:

```
\begin{quote}
  I'm a fuel-injected suicide machine! I am a rocker, I am a roller, 
  I am an out-of-controller! \hfill (Crawford "Nightrider" Montizano)
\end{quote}
```

If you have to show were exactly the quote one can find, write it in the sentence before or after the quote.

Comment: Thanks for the `\hfill` idea. I suppose in scientific documents the exact position of the quoted text needs to be stated. Would `[...] controller! \hfill \citep[p.~123]{Nightrider1979} \end{quote}` be a solution?